# Xamarin iOS - UITextField padding with left image

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm already setting the LeftView of my UITextField so that I can draw a little icon next to the text.

```
Password.LeftView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("LockAndKey"));
Password.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
```

This works great but the problem now is that the placeholder and actual text is too close to the image - I'd like to indent over the text.

What do I need to do in Xamarin/iOS for my subclassed UITextField to indent the text with a margin? I know there are various functions I can override but haven't had success with it for the text so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to extend/subclass the UITextField class and override the method called `DrawText` . There you add the padding you need.

```
    public override void DrawText(CGRect rect)
    {
        var padding = new UIEdgeInsets (0, 10, 0, 0);

        base.DrawText( padding.InsetRect(rect));
    }
```

This will add a 10 points padding to the left.

To make it more customizable I'd add a property called Padding where basically you can set the padding you need depending on the situation.

*** UPDATE #1 ***

In the case you want to have the space while typing you can just make the UIImageView that represent your LeftView a little bigger in width and play with the ViewContentMode

Using your example:

```
var leftView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("LockAndKey"));
leftView.Frame = new CGRect (leftView.Frame.X, leftView.Frame.Y, leftView.Frame.Width + 15, leftView.Frame.Height);
leftView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center;

Password.LeftView = leftView
Password.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
```

With this configuration you will have 7.5 points on each size of the ImageView. You can use others ContentMode to make it work as you'd like.

**** UPDATE #2 ****

Just found another way.

In your subclass UITextField override these two methods:

```
    public override CGRect TextRect (CGRect forBounds)
    {
        var padding = new UIEdgeInsets (0, 20, 0, 0);

        return base.TextRect (padding.InsetRect(forBounds));
    }

    public override CGRect EditingRect (CGRect forBounds)
    {
        return TextRect (forBounds);
    }
```

This one is cleaner and as the first solution you can customize it.

Comment: This worked for the text after I type it in, but not for the placeholder, or when i'm typing.  Are there additional overrides I can do for those?:) thanks so much for taking the time to help me!